# How to show text only menu for menu-control item in outlook web add-in using office API?

Tags: xml, outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing Outlook Web Add-In using javascript/html/css.

I have created a Menu control having 3 items on Home Ribbon. I need to show text only menus for it. But when I comment the following code

```
<Item id="settings">
    <Label resid="settingsLabel"/>
    <Supertip>
        <Title resid="settingsLabel" />
        <Description resid="settingsToolTip" />
    </Supertip>
    <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="trans" />
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="trans" />
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="trans" />
    </Icon>
    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
       <FunctionName>openSettingsDialog</FunctionName>
    </Action>
</Item>
```

It shows default icon (See Image)
And,when I use transparent icon.It looks like

Answer (score 0):

According manifest schema for [`Item`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/control#child-elements) element the image for the menu `Item` is required and must be specified in [`Icon`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/icon) element. Three image sizes are required (16, 32, and 80 pixels) while five other sizes are supported (20, 24, 40, 48, and 64 pixels).

Comment: Ok.But when I adds transparent icon,it works well but when I hover on item,icon turns into visible form.

Comment: @NehaSoni It sounds like you are trying to hack menu item to make it without icon, when by design it must be there. The icon is for the reason. For some of the supported clients the icon is the only visual piece which would represent your command (no title shown). If you make it transparent and there is no title what would be the user experience? Where as the user I have to click? If you sutisfied with the answer consider to accept it. Accepting Answers: [How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)